# Is it possible to translate an ImageView on the android platform using Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

For example, if I loaded an image into an ImageView as such:

```
Imeteor = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.meteor1);
Picasso.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.red_meteor)
                .resize((int) meteorWidth, (int) meteorHeight)
                .into(Imeteor);
```

Is it then possible to translate (move across or around the screen) said ImageView using Picasso? The current method I am using is below.

```
 Imeteor = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.meteor1);
 Imeteor.setX(meteorXPosition);
 Imeteor.setY(meteorYPosition);
```

With the values of "meteorXPosition", and "meteorYPosition" being updated in a separate method from where the image is loaded. Also, "meteorXPosition", and "meteorYPosition" are updated every millisecond.

Or,

By the fact that the image is loaded using Picasso, does that mean that the every time the ImageView is accessed it is accessed through Picasso? For example, by the code I provided above

```
 Imeteor = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.meteor1);
 Imeteor.setX(meteorXPosition);
 Imeteor.setY(meteorYPosition);
```

Comment: Picasso simply loads an image into an ImageView. You can still utilize the ImageView as you would normally. Picasso does provide scaling options and such, though.

Comment: Thanks, so if I'm reading this correctly your saying Picasso only handles processes done to the image within the imageView?

Comment: That is correct. The ImageView is a container that Picasso loads into. What you do with that container (e.g. where it is placed) is still ultimately under the control of the ImageView.

Comment: That sucks, Picasso makes things so much easier, I'd hoped it'd make image translation easier to.

Comment: Translation should be fairly simple. You are currently using 2 lines of code.

Comment: I neglected to include much of my code. Though the translation side is fairly simple. I'm just trying to optimize my code right now, and hoped Picasso would help. I think my current problem stems from when I load my Images. Everything loads smoothly, and the UI doesn't stagger, but there is a noticeable delay from when the meteor appears to when it is told to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124080/discussion-between-holycatcrusher-and-zgc7009).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might read this, and doesn't bother to read the comments. Picasso only handles loading the bitmap, and performing transformations on the bitmap in the image view. For moving a bitmap within an image view an option is to use the image view's setX() and setY() function. Which moves the the image view to a new location (the bitmap is in the image view). For moving images it is best to look up how to move an image view.